# İonic How to send notifications user to user via FCM?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I can send notification  on firebase console but I want to when user send message on app then another user get notification.I searched but could not find.How can I do it ?

I use this for firebase console  to user <https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase>

EDIT :

```
public initPush(){
    if(Capacitor.platform!=='web'){
      this.registerPush();
    }
  }
  private registerPush(){
    PushNotifications.requestPermission().then((permission)=>{
      if(permission.granted) {
        PushNotifications.register();
      }
    });
    PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
      (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
        //alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
      }
    );
    
    PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError',
      (error: any) => {
        alert('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
     PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived',
     async (notification: PushNotification) => {
        //alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
        const toast = await this.toastController.create({
          position:"top",
          header:notification.title,
          message: notification.body,
          duration: 9000,
          buttons:[{text:"Aç", handler: () => {
            console.log('Favorite clicked');
            this.router.navigateByUrl(`/main/tabs/message`);
          }},
        {text: 'Kapat',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        } }],
        });
        
        toast.present(); 
      }
    );

    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
     async (notification:PushNotificationActionPerformed)=>{
       //const data =notification.notification.data;
       console.log('Action performed:'+JSON.stringify(notification.notification));
         this.router.navigateByUrl(`/main/tabs/message`);
    });
}
```

Comment: in which technology your backend/API code is ?

Comment: I am using ionic, angular and firebase @TaylorRahul

Comment: I have added my comment below please refer this

Comment: thanks for your answer :) I'll try and come back.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @AvivLo yes ofcourse I put the code but it's just as I said send notification firebase console to all users

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS module is available for this I have added its link below. but for this you need device token of the user whom you want to send notification this might not be available at application end it should be in your database so a good practice is to send this notification from backend API.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node

Comment: "Warning: on February 2, 2017, the Firebase Team released the admin.messaging() service to their node.js admin module. This new service makes this module kind of deprecated"    is it working ?